# Deserialize XML to dynamically created class in Java

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson, deserialization

I have a set of abstract classes like this:

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract B getB() {return this.b;}

    public abstract void setB(B b) {this.b = b;}
}

abstract class B {
    public abstract C getC() {return this.c;}

    public abstract void setC(C c) {this.c = c;}
}

abstract class C {
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {return this.foo;}

    public void setFoo(String foo) {this.foo = foo;}
}
```

In runtime, I create proxies for these classes using [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/). I can easily serialize objects of these proxy classes to XML. But when I attempt to deserialize an XML, JAXB throws  `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of A` since it can't create instances of abstract classes. I want to show it how to create these instances in runtime in order to deserialize them (I have a special Spring bean, which does it - so I need to be able to inject it wherever I define creation logic) I looked at JAXB and Jackson, but couldn't find how to do it.

Is there a way to do it? I'm not bound to any serialization framework, though it would be preferable to stay with JAXB or Jackson.

Comment: could you show a sample xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that both JAXB and Jackson can do it.

JAXB provides two ways to solve it: factory methods and adapters.

1. Using JAXB factory methods, I need to create a factory which would be responsible for object creation:

   ```
   public class MyFactory {
       public static MyObject createMyObject() {
           return SomeMagic.createMyObject();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then I only need to mark my abstract class with `@XmlType` annotation:

   ```
   @XmlType(factoryClass = MyFactory.class, factoryMethod = "createMyObject")
   public abstract class MyObject {
        ...
   }
   ```
2. If I wanted to use JAXB adapters, I would need to create Java classes which JAXB can instantiate and fill from the XML, and then I would need to convert objects of these classes to the ones I need:

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MyAdapter.MyJaxbObject, MyObject> {
       @Override
       public MyObject unmarshal(MyJaxbObject src) throws Exception {
           MyObject tgt = SomeMagic.createMyObject();
           BeanUtils.copyProperties(tgt, src);
           return tgt;
       }

       @Override
       public MyObject marshal(MyObject src) throws Exception {
           MyJaxbObject tgt = new MyJaxbObject();
           BeanUtils.copyProperties(tgt, src);
           return tgt;
       }

       public static class MyJaxbObject {
          ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Then I would mark my abstract class with `@XmlJavaAdapter` annotation:

   ```
   @XmlJavaAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
   public abstract class MyObject {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Using Jackson I can create custom deserializer for my abstract class.

   ```
   public class MyObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyObject> {
       public MyObjectDeserializer() {
           super(MyObject.class);
       }

       @Override
       public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
           ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
           MyObject myObject = SomeMagic.createMyObject();
           return mapper.readerForUpdating(myObject).readValue(parser);
       }
   }
   ```

   Later in my code I need to register my deserializers:

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
   SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("module", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
   module.addDeserializer(MyObject.class, new MyObjectDeserializer());
   mapper.registerModule(module);
   ```

For my purposes I preferred Jackson custom deserializers, because:

1. I also need to perform additional operations on the nested objects after their fields are filled but before passing these objects to other objects' setters (JAXB doesn't seem to support it)
2. I can use custom logic when I fill object's fields (Also achievable with Adapters).
3. I can create deserializers by myself, so I can use dependency injection to configure them (Factories are static, and Adapters are created by JAXB).